# highcharter linkedto legend not working

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I've tried to recreate this example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6gw5P/239/

```
highchart() %>%  
  hc_chart(type=list('bar')) %>%
  hc_xAxis(list(categories=c('Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'))) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar=list(stacking = 'normal')) %>%
  hc_series(
    list(
      name =  'John and Joe',
      data = c(5, 3, 4, 7, 2),
      stack = 'Male'
    ),
    list(
      linkedTo ='Previous',
      name = "Joe",
      data =c(2, 5, 6, 2, 1),
      stack = 'Male'
      ),
      list(
        name =  'Jane and Janet',
        data = c(2, 5, 6, 2, 1),
        stack = 'Female'
      ),
      list(
        linkedTo ='Previous',
        name = "Janet",
        data =c(3, 0, 4, 4, 3),
        stack = 'Female'
      ))
```

It works in the sense that there is no legend displayed for Joe and Janet but when clicking on the legends de (de)selection does not work for both. Is this not integrated yet in `higcharter` ?

Comment: Shouldn't be there `':previous'` instead of `'Previous'`? `':previous'` is a keyword in Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I bothered you for this....... so bad